# Need some explanation for this code

Tags: c, string, c99

I found this c99 code. Can someone explain what's really happening in here?

```
for(char const * i = "*****";printf("%s\n",i + 4) < 6;i--);
```

Comment: Not off-hand.  The code is too bad for inspection.

Comment: Yo initialize a pointer to a litreal string ***** ' then you print from back to end the string
The i + 4 is because the pinter size is 4 bits and not 1 as a nornal char

Comment: @ScottHunter No, it declares it to be pointer to const char, the pointer is not constant

Comment: const or no const, the code is so bad that it would get you fired or a F- grade, depending on the environment.  You only find code this bad in academic gunge, eg. homework.

Comment: What does `printf` return? Get into the habit of reading man pages when you do not understand a code.

Comment: Ok got this ,it just skiping array to last address and printing from there to first index address line by line, :D . @thingy i found this from meme comment :) just curiosity .thats why aske it :)

Comment: @namila007 abbreviating user names won't send them a flag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me dissect that line:

```
for(char const * i = "*****";printf("%s\n",i + 4) < 6;i--);
```

First part of the `for` loop condition: `char const * i = "*****";` is just a pointer to 5 star characters. `i+1` would point to `****`, `i+2` would point to `***` and so on.

The second part prints the given number of stars: `printf("%s\n",i + 4)`.Typically in this part of the `for` loop, we use something like `i < n`. Here, instead of `i` we get result of `printf`.

Take a look at `man 3 printf` to understand it:

> RETURN VALUE
>          Upon successful return, these functions return the number of characters printed (excluding the null byte used to end output to strings).

So basically we printf the smaller parts of the `i` string until printf returns `6` as the number of characters printed.

Comment: Printf must return 6 to stop. Not 5. But the \n is included here.

Answer (score 1):

This is what it prints:-

```
*
**
***
****
*****
```

Key points to remember:-

- `printf` returns no of characters printed
- `for` loop executes till the condition evaluates to true
- i is initialized to the last start in the const string and shifts left by 1 star per iteration

Answer (score 1):

```
This might make it more clear:

char*i = "12345";
int charsPrinted = printf( "%s\n", i + 4 );
while ( charsPrinted < 6 )
{
    i--;
    charsPrinted = printf( "%s\n", i + 4 );
}
```

But it is likely to crash.  To break the loop, charsPrinted must reach 6, and that means `i` no longer points to the string start.  It's not really valid at that point.  It might work, but it depends.  Without a crash, this would be printed:

```
5
45
345
2345
12345
```